# Understanding the Rake Routes output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is what I get if I do a rake routes:

```
population_management GET /population_management/:id(.:format)          population_management#show
                      GET /providers/:provider_id/scorecards(.:format)  scorecard#show
                      GET /patients/:id/summary(.:format)               patients#show
```

Notice the first one at the very left does have like an extra column that its value is population_managment but the second and third ones do not have that, they just start with `GET`.

What is the difference between the first one and the other two? Which one is more professional and better to do? Is there some sort of rule of thumb or a convention that Rail developers follow to determine which of these is better?

```
  resources :population_management, only: [:show]

  match 'providers/:provider_id/scorecards', to: 'scorecard#show', via: :get
  match 'patients/:id/summary', to: 'patients#show', via: :get
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column is the name of the route, which is useful for things like setting up links (where you could use, for example `population_management_path(id)` instead of having to hardcode `/population_management/id`.

If you want to name your own custom routes, you can do that using `:as`, eg.

```
match 'patients/:id/summary', to: 'patients#show', via: :get, as: "patient_summary"
# or slightly simpler
get 'patients/:id/summary', to: 'patients#show', as: "patient_summary"
```

(You will need to use the latter in Rails 4, given `match` is being deprecated).

Either method is fine, although `resources` (and `resource`) are much more convenient when you're setting up standard RESTful resources and don't want to have to define all the routes individually.

As always, the [Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is good reading on the subject too, and worth checking out.

Comment: Great. Thanks. So it is more recommended to use "resources" like the first one that I did,  that way fiding path and URL is also easier and also it is the Rails 3 way of doing routes AND when I need a CUSTOM sort of route I should use that "AS" thing and do the customization in there.... Correct?

Comment: Yeah, if you need a custom or unusual route (or if you don't want to set up a resource to only use one of the routes), go ahead a create a custom one. Giving it a name using `:as` is a good idea though, as it will give you a level of abstraction instead of having to hard code in the route wherever you need it (which will help you out a lot if you ever want to change the route).